# Burninate cheat?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Why do we need a tag called [cheat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cheat)?

Supposedly this is related to cheats in computer games, but seems to be used for various other purposes as well. I don't quite see why someone would be interested in searching for "cheat", it seems like a pointless tag.

Comment: That's indeed a useless tag. Lets take out [tag:cheating] too though.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That tag is cheating; it should not be there and will be burninated!

I'll take down the [cheating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cheating) tag too.

---

I have haz burninated the cheating [cheat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cheat) and [cheating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cheating) tags. With FIRE.

[image: tag burninated]

♫♩ Burninating the countryside ♪♬ burninating the peasants ♫♩ burninating all the peoples ♬♪ in the thatch roofed cottages! ♬♩

*Wicked dueling guitar-solos*.

They'll be gone completely with the next zombie tag cleanup run.

Comment: I love you guys so much